# How can I write content different column sized data frames into single final output text file using spark2

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I have 6  Dataset  of each different sized columns, i need put all those 6 Datasets content into one  single text file, how can i do it in Spark2 java.

I tried union , but that is  not working as column count is not matching for any Dataset

Comment: can you please provide a minimal example? do all the datasets have the same number of rows?

Comment: If you plan to write to write to text files then you should just map them all to Dataset[String], each record translates into a line (String) - it's up to you what's the string representation of the record for each Dataset, depending on how you plan to consume the text files (fields may be written tab separated, you may generate json, etc.) and then you should be able to union all Dataset[String] and save to text files.